# importerror: No module named django in windows 7

Tags: python, django, git

I have looked into post with the same problem as mine but never got lucky to find solution of mine. I have installed python 3.4.1 and and install django through git. I have also set my environment variable **PATH** to **C:\Python34\Scripts** but everytime I type django-admin --version in my command promt, it says not recognize as internal or external command and when using python shell when I type import django it says importerror: No module named django. What am I missing here? Please help. Thanks a lot.

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "installed django by git"? Git is not a Python package manager, it can't install things (kind of like "I bought my computer at FedEx" - it only delivers stuff). [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/windows/) are instructions on how to install django on a Windows system.

Comment: I mean to clone..git clone git://github.com/django/django.git django-trunk

Comment: I installed django by cloning it in git and not by using pip

Comment: You *downloaded* django by cloning it with git. What did you do that qualifies as *installing*? Where is it placed? How did you let Python know where to find it? (I submit, as your last picture clearly shows, that your Python has no clue that something got installed.) Specifically, look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path): if you do `import django`, you should have `django.py` in current dir, or in Python's repository (or you should modify `sys.path` to add to the search path yourself). `pip` will place the package in the proper location.

Comment: Thank you. I thought cloning it will do. It is working now by using pip install django command